# How to play MP4 with Ursina in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, game-engine, ursina

I am new to game development. I am trying to start high and make a 3D RPG. I know the road is not gonna be easy. That is why i decided to use Ursina and python to make my game.

However i wanna add a cutscene showing a Backstory. I have the video in mp4 format but i cannot seem to know how to play it inside the game with Ursina.

Anyhelp will be much appreciated.
(Side question : do you think Ursina is good for a beginner in 3D gaming? If i want to publish my game on my website, isn't it better for me to learn javascript ? I read about Unity but it is too big to download for a little side project)

Comment: As for your side question, Ursina has many things built in but will still require you to do coding and have a good understanding of various 3D concepts. It all depends on your background. You don't have to learn JavaScript to publish your game.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the video as a texture of any element. You'll want to fix it to the UI using its `parent` attribute and you have to load the sound separately from the same file (as described in the [Panda3D documentation](https://docs.panda3d.org/1.10/python/programming/texturing/playing-mpg-and-avi-files)).

```py
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

video = 'video.mp4'
video_player = Entity(model='quad', parent=camera.ui, scale=(1.5, 1), texture=video)
video_sound = loader.loadSfx(video)
video_player.texture.synchronizeTo(video_sound)
video_sound.play()

app.run()
```

The above code assumes that the video file is in the same folder as the Python script.

Comment: Can we loop the video?

Comment: @ShashvatKumar sure, just set `video_sound.setLoop(True)`

Answer (score 2):

From Entity Basics in the documentation:

`e4 = Entity(model='cube', texture='movie_name.mp4') # set video texture`

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't think there is a way to do that. the closest thing you can do to that is having a folder filled with all the frames of your video in .png or .jpg files, then adding a quad to the world and changing the texture of it to the next frame every fraction of a second depending on the framerate. this, however would make your computer l a g. trust me, I've tried it. it would probably be better to have a separate window with some sort of module that plays .mp4 files for playing the file.
In other words, there is no feasible way to do that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is possible and feasible in most of the cases.