# Ursina Engine: video desynch problems when the same video file is played again

Tags: python, ursina

I noticed that every time I play the same video twice with Ursina Entity video player I get a desynch between the video and audio because the video does not start at the first frame but at a later time, and it loops over as it ends too early.

I found a similar post where it is described how to extract audio from mp4 video files and synch audio with video [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68248623/how-to-play-mp4-with-ursina-in-python) but I'd like to keep the audio and video files separate.

I suppose it is a problem of unloading the buffer in Panda3D, I attempted several texture/buffer cleaning functions without any success.

I also tried adding several delays to give the engine the time to load audio and videos properly, but I suspect that it is a problem of anticipation rather than delay.

Here's my code:

```
    #load and playing audio
    audio_entity = Audio('audio/' + audio_file+ '.wav', loop=False, autoplay=True)
    trial_length = audio_entity.length
    destroy(audio_entity, delay=trial_length)

    #load and play video
    video_entity = Entity(model='cube', texture='video/'+video_file + '.mp4', scale_x=0.8, scale_y=0.8, alpha=0, parent=camera.ui)  # set video texture
    video_entity.fade_in(value=1, duration=0.3)
    video_entity.fade_out(value=0, duration=0.3, delay=trial_length)
    destroy(video_entity, delay=trial_length)
```